# Does the Guards And Wards's Gust Of Wind effect tamper with the Guards And Wards's fog effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, vision-and-light

In Pathfinder the spell Guards and Wards creates - among many other effects - magical fog inside your fortress or lair. In addition you can add one of five effects, one of which is a Gust Of Wind in a corridor. Now, does that Gust of Wind effect disperse the fog as normal fog even though it was created from the same spell and caster, or is the fog one of a kind so that it can't be dispersed by wind?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, it does

The *fog* effect created by [Guards and Wards](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/guards-and-wards/) affects all corridors in the structure protected by the spell.

> Fog: Fog fills all corridors, obscuring all sight, including darkvision, beyond 5 feet. A creature within 5 feet has concealment (attacks have a 20% miss chance). Creatures farther away have total concealment (50% miss chance, and the attacker cannot use sight to locate the target).

However, the [Gust of Wind](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gust-of-wind/) effect will affect a single corridor or room, and no exception was given about how it handles the fog created by the spell. As such, if placed in a corridor (and not a room), the spell will behave normally and blow away the fog in *that* corridor:

> In addition to the effects noted, a gust of wind can do anything that a sudden blast of wind would be expected to do. It can create a stinging spray of sand or dust, fan a large fire, overturn delicate awnings or hangings, heel over a small boat, and **blow gases or vapors to the edge of its range**.

Answer (score 2):

## This GM would have [*guards and wards*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/guards-and-wards/)' fog unaffected by any [*gust of wind*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gust-of-wind/)

While the spell [*guards and wards*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/guards-and-wards/) does create a magical fog throughout the warded area, that magical fog's entire description is this:

> Fog fills all corridors, obscuring all sight, including darkvision, beyond 5 feet. A creature within 5 feet has concealment (attacks have a 20% miss chance). Creatures farther away have total concealment (50% miss chance, and the attacker cannot use sight to locate the target). *Saving Throw:* none. *Spell Resistance:* no.

Later the spell says, "A [*dispel magic*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/) cast on a specific effect, if successful, removes only that effect."

Unlike, for example, the effect of the spell [*fog cloud*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fog-cloud/) that a "moderate wind (11+ mph) disperses… in 4 rounds [and] a strong wind (21+ mph) disperses… in 1 round" and other similar spells like [*obscuring mist*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/obscuring-mist/), [*veil of ash*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/veil-of-ash/), and even [*mind fog*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mind-fog/), there's no mention in the *guards and wards* spell of winds of any kind having an effect on the magical fog created by the spell *guards and wards*.

In short, because the *guards and wards* spell's magical fog effect doesn't mention being affected by wind, this GM wouldn't have the *guards and wards* own [*gust of wind*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gust-of-wind/) effect (or, for that matter, any other [*gust of wind*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gust-of-wind/) effect) "blow [the fog] vapors to the edge of its range."

This means wanderers within a *guards and wards* magical fog effect must tough it out or negate the fog effect with a *dispel magic* spell, the 6th-level spell's fog effect remaining in place in the face of *any* wind effect… which, to this GM, seems appropriate for a spell of its power and limited utility.

However, this player wouldn't flip the table and leave the campaign of a GM who ruled that the *guards and wards* spell's own *gust of wind* effect effectively leaves one place in his PC's stronghold fog-free like [this fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131040/8610) suggests. I mean, seriously, it would take highly unusual circumstances for this player to have his PC pick the *gust of wind* effect when the *guards and wards* spell makes available deterrents that are bigger (like [*stinking cloud*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stinking-cloud/)), deadlier (like [*suggestion*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/suggestion/)), and creepier (like [*magic mouth*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-mouth/)).